# how can i save the index of maximum number in the list, Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a sample list:
l = [1,2,3,12,4,5,6,12]

I am going to make a index list from the max. (it can be one maximum or more than two maximum.)

```
a=max(l)
dd=[]
for num in l:
    if a==num:
        ind=l.index(a)
        dd.append(ind)        
print(dd)
```

but the output in my code is : [3,3] how can i reach to the [3,7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
l = [1,2,3,12,4,5,6,12]
a=max(l)

dd=[]
for ind, num in enumerate(l):
    if a==num:
        dd.append(ind)        
print(dd)
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your previous code doesn't work since `list.index` gives you the index of the first item, which will always be 3, so for `ind=l.index(a)`, the value of `ind=3` always.

So we need to iterate over the list for finding indexes of all maximum values. list-comprehension can be used for this.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 12, 4, 5, 6, 12]
#Find the indexes where the value equals maximum value, 
#while iterating over the list using enumerate
max_l = max(l)
li = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(l) if val == max_l]
print(li)
#[3, 7]
```